# Blocking Farm account from retrieving audit for specific site collection [For QA tests]

Tags: 2013, configuration, auditing

I would like to know if there is a "trick" to block the capacity of FARM account user to retrieve audit from specific site collection while that FARM account user is able to retrieve audit from other site collections both site collections are located under the same site.

Comment: Just to clarify that we need the special configuration, in order to reproduce bug that has been discovered in our customer.

Answer (score 1):

A Farm Admin has the right to grant themselves access to any resources within the farm. While there is nothing scoped at the Site Collection level, you can put a Deny resource at the Web Application level, which that Farm Administrator could then adjusted as they wish, which makes such a move fairly pointless.